# Auto Increment on Composite Primary Key - Sqlite3 + Python

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a code like this

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS base (ID INTEGER NOT NULL, col2 TEXT NOT NULL, col3 INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(ID, col2))')
```

This code gives me an **sqlite3.IntegrityError** exception even though I am very sure that I am writing the record for the first time.

So, I tried

```
c.execute('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS base (ID INTEGER, col2 TEXT, col3 INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY(ID, col2))')
```

This inserts the row fine in the **base** table BUT, ID column is not auto incremented at all.

What can I do? Any idea?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In sqlite, you only get autoincrement behavior when only one integer column is the primary key.  composite keys prevent autoincrement from taking effect.

You can get a similar result by defining `id` as the only primary key, but then adding an additional unique constraint on `id, col3`.

If that's still not quite what you want (say, id's don't need to be unique at all), you probably will have to use a trigger to make autoincrement work.

Comment: Great! Thanks for explaining this. I think I will go with making ID as primary key integer and add Unique constraint on Col2. Thank you!