# Use of composite keys with an AUTOINCREMENT column in SQLite database

Tags: sqlite, primary-key, auto-increment, composite-key

I've created a table which has a column "_id" which is an INTEGER type with  AUTOINCREMENT. Now I know that a column which is on AUTOINCREMENT has to be a PRIMARY KEY , which is the syntax if I'm not wrong. But I want Composite keys so I don't declare the "_id" as `(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT)`with the PRIMARY KEY defintion in the column definition but declare it as `(_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT UNIQUE, password TEXT, name TEXT, phonenumber TEXT, address TEXT, fine INTEGER, bookid INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (_id, username, password))`

But it gives a runtime error. Is it the case that when we have an AUTOINCREMENT field it's compulsory to declare the PRIMARY KEY in the column definition itself?

Here's the error

```
07-18 12:47:22.916: E/AndroidRuntime(3423): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "AUTOINCREMENT": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE userdetails (_id INTEGER AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT UNIQUE, password TEXT, name TEXT, phonenumber TEXT, address TEXT, fine INTEGER, bookid INTEGER, PRIMARY KEY (_id, username, password));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the column does not need to be a primary key. However, SQLite allows AUTOINCREMENT only if one key is set as primary key. Here multiple columns are set as Primary Key. Hence auto increment on one of them does not work.

Refer to the answer to this stackoverflow post :

[Auto Increment on Composite Primary Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6793205/auto-increment-on-composite-primary-key-sqlite3-python)

Comment: Incorrect. According to the [SQLite documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html) "AUTOINCREMENT is not allowed ... on any table column other than INTEGER PRIMARY KEY". The [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6793274/2012372) in the linked question does provide an effective workaround without using a trigger.