# add unique constraint in room database to multiple column

Tags: android, sqlite, database-design, android-room, android-architecture-components

I have one entity in room

```
@Entity(foreignKeys ={
        @ForeignKey(entity = Label.class, parentColumns = "_id", childColumns = "labelId", onDelete = CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Task.class, parentColumns = "_id", childColumns = "taskId", onDelete = CASCADE)
})
public class LabelOfTask extends Data{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "labelId")
    private Integer labelId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "taskId")
    private Integer taskId;
}
```

sql syntax of this entity is as below

```
CREATE TABLE `LabelOfTask` (
    `_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
     `labelId` INTEGER,
     `taskId` INTEGER,
     FOREIGN KEY(`labelId`) REFERENCES `Label`(`_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE ,
     FOREIGN KEY(`taskId`) REFERENCES `Task`(`_id`) ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
```

but what change or annotation I need to add in entity class if I want to append below constraint to the auto generated sql schema of the table

```
unique (labelId, taskId)
```

Ultimately I want to make combination of labelId and taskId unique in a table(or entity of room) using room library.

Comment: A plain UNIQUE constraint on a column, other than via an index, is not supported.

Comment: index? you mean primary key?

Answer (score 121, accepted):

**A plain UNIQUE constraint on a column, other than via an index, is not supported.**

You can enforce this uniqueness property by setting the unique property of an @Index annotation to true. The following code sample (Java) prevents a table from having two rows that contain the same set of values for the firstName and lastName columns:

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"first_name", "last_name"},
        unique = true)})
class User {
    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "first_name")
    public String firstName;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "last_name")
    public String lastName;

    @Ignore
    Bitmap picture;
}
```

The Kotlin equivalent of the annotation is given below:

```
@Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["first_name", "last_name"], unique = true)])
```

In your code you can do the following changes to have UNIQUE constraints

```
@Entity(foreignKeys ={
        @ForeignKey(entity = Label.class, parentColumns = "_id", childColumns = "labelId", onDelete = CASCADE),
        @ForeignKey(entity = Task.class, parentColumns = "_id", childColumns = "taskId", onDelete = CASCADE)},
        indices = {@Index(value = {"labelId", "taskId"},
                unique = true)}
)
public class LabelOfTask extends Data{
    @ColumnInfo(name = "labelId")
    private Integer labelId;
    @ColumnInfo(name = "taskId")
    private Integer taskId;
}
```

Comment: What about setting a single property as UNIQUE ?

Comment: I have tried to answer your question, but I think I paste in wrong place :) Please check it below :D

Comment: Hi! What happens if you try to add a second identical value?

Comment: For Kotlin you can write it this way:   foreignKeys = [ForeignKey(
        entity = Label::class,
        parentColumns = ["_id"],
        childColumns = ["labelId"],
        onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE)],
    indices = [Index(value = ["labelId", "taskId"], unique = true)]

Comment: Is this the example of creating the composite unique key using two columns (first_name, last_name)  ??  or  Is it the example of creating two separate unique keys using two different columns ??

Comment: @Valeriy  a conflict will occur and will based on your defined conflict strategy.

Comment: I wonder why Android room API doesn't support a single column unique constraint such as adding `@Unique` annotation to the column definition.

Answer (score 56):

If you wonder to make a single column to be unique, only need to write

```
@Entity(indices = [Index(value = ["name"], unique = true)])
```

Comment: How to create composite unique key and composite primary key ??

Comment: @KPradeepKumarReddy there's a primaryKeys field in the Entity annotation for that

Answer (score 13):

For a single column Uniqueness

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"first_name"},unique = true)})
```

For Multiple column Uniqueness

```
@Entity(indices = {@Index(value = {"first_name", "last_name"},unique = true)})
```

Answer (score 4):

If manually migrating your Room DB to add an index using SQL statements, your index name to be able to match the annotation on the table must be of the format:

```
...
database.execSQL("CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_tableName_columnName ON tableName (columnName)")
...
```

Not sure how long the index names can be, so not sure what it looks like with multi-column indexes.

Comment: @GertArnold I'm sure it isn't, and I could write a complete answer that also adds the caveat I just mentioned, but I personally don't like when the same answer is repeated multiple times (especially when it's clear your answer is weeks or months later), so I just listed the caveat, which might not answer the original question, but it does relate to it and other questions asked. And yes, comments aren't for discussion either.

Comment: The caveat isn't necessary. It's off-topic. Everything is about generated migration code here.

Answer (score 1):

You can also achieve multi column uniqueness by composite primary key (entity is uniquely identified by a combination of multiple columns).

```
@Entity(primaryKeys = ["firstName", "lastName"])
data class User(
    val firstName: String?,
    val lastName: String?
)
```

[See official docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data#composite-key)

Note that in this case you cannot use auto-generated increment of id, [SQLite doesn't support that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6793274/4815718).