# Android: Why is Room so slow?

Tags: sqlite, kotlin, android-room, dao

I am working on a simple database procedure in Kotlin using Room, and I can't explain why the process is so slow, mostly on the Android Studio emulator.

The table I am working on is this:

```
@Entity(tableName = "folders_items_table", indices = arrayOf(Index(value = ["folder_name"]), Index(value = ["item_id"])))
data class FoldersItems(
        @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
        var uid: Long = 0L,

        @ColumnInfo(name = "folder_name")
        var folder_name: String = "",

        @ColumnInfo(name = "item_id")
        var item_id: String = ""

)
```

And what I am just trying to do is this: checking if a combination folder/item is already present, insert a new record. If not, ignore it. on the emulator, it takes up to 7-8 seconds to insert 100 records. On a real device, it is much faster, but still, it takes around 3-4 seconds which is not acceptable for just 100 records. It looks like the "insert" query is particularly slow.

Here is the procedure that makes what I have just described (inside a coroutine):

```
val vsmFoldersItems = FoldersItems()

items.forEach{

    val itmCk = database.checkFolderItem(item.folder_name, it)


    if (itmCk == 0L) {


        val newFolderItemHere = vsmFoldersItems.copy(
                                            folder_name = item.folder_name,
                                            item_id = it
        )
    
        database.insertFolderItems(newFolderItemHere)

    }
    
}
```

the variable "items" is an array of Strings.

Here is the DAO definitions of the above-called functions:

```
@Query("SELECT uid FROM folders_items_table WHERE folder_name = :folder AND item_id = :item")
    fun checkFolderItem(folder: String, item: String): Long

@Insert
    suspend fun insertFolderItems(item: FoldersItems)
```

Comment: I think you should just [create an unique index](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48962768/9241978) out of your value columns and just run one batch insert instead of looping and running a check query followed by insert query for every single item.

Comment: Thank you @Pawel, I tried that but the fact is that since this procedure is called asynchronously, as soon as the insert query tries to store a value already there, it makes an exception and the loop is broken. So, I have to stick with my simple query check... thanks anyway!

Comment: What exception does it make? If I wasn't clear by "batch insert" I meant to modify (or add new) DAO method `insertFolderItems` to consume entire list with `OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE` and you wouldn't have any loop whatsoever.

Comment: Good point @Pawel, I didn't think about that. I'll try that tomorrow and report. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the loop inside a single transaction should significantly reduce the time taken.

The reason is that each transaction (by default each SQL statement that makes a change to the database) will result in a disk write. So that's 100 disk writes for your loop.

If you begin a transaction before the loop and then set the transaction successful when the loop is completed and then end the transaction a single disk write is required.

What I am unsure of is exactly how to do this when using a suspended function (not that familiar with Kotlin).

As such I'd suggest either dropping the suspend or having another Dao for use within loops.

Then have something like :-

```
val vsmFoldersItems = FoldersItems()
your_RoomDatabase.beginTransaction()
items.forEach{

    val itmCk = database.checkFolderItem(item.folder_name, it)


    if (itmCk == 0L) {


        val newFolderItemHere = vsmFoldersItems.copy(
                                            folder_name = item.folder_name,
                                            item_id = it
        )
    
        database.insertFolderItems(newFolderItemHere)

    }
    
}
your_RoomDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful() //<<<<<<< IF NOT set then ALL updates will be rolled back
your_RoomDatabase.endTransaction()
```

You may wish to refer to:-

- https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase

You may wish to especially refer to **[runInTransaction](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase#runInTransaction(java.util.concurrent.Callable%3CV%3E))**

Comment: Just have that code in an abstract method inside the DAO class (convert it from an interface to an abstract class first) and annotate the method with @Transaction. The entire method should then be executed in a single transaction.

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you guys! I endedup using the runInTransaction() which is the most current one, and now the loop takes less than a second. Thank you again very much!

Comment: Hey Mike, I am just using select query in 2000 rows but it takes litterly 6 to 8 sec to fetch data? can you help me with that ?

Comment: @gulabpatel Have you found any solution?

Comment: for those coming here and wanting the coroutines solution, use `appDatabase.withTransaction { ... }`